# SQL group result in one row

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the I site a database that handles 7 different languages, I want to return in one row all the `post_content` in one row.
Example:
fr_content,en_content,es_content,int_content...
My current sql is returning 7 rows
[image]

My sql is:

```
SELECT p.ID, t.trid, ptrans.*, pen.post_content
    FROM hex_posts p
    JOIN hex_icl_translations t 
        ON p.ID = t.element_id
    LEFT JOIN hex_icl_translations ptrans
        on ptrans.trid = t.trid
    LEFT JOIN hex_posts pen
        on pen.ID = ptrans.element_id
    WHERE  
        p.ID =  22790
    ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

The `ID` 22790 is the original post, `element_id` is the post translated.

Any idea how to group all this rows in just one?

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to read all languages at one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use group_concat()

```
SELECT p.ID, t.trid, ptrans.*, group_concat(pen.post_content SEPARATOR ', ')
        FROM hex_posts p
        JOIN hex_icl_translations t 
            ON p.ID = t.element_id
        LEFT JOIN hex_icl_translations ptrans
            on ptrans.trid = t.trid
        LEFT JOIN hex_posts pen
            on pen.ID = ptrans.element_id
        WHERE  
            p.ID =  22790
    group by p.ID, t.trid
        ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Comment: Don't forget the reset default group_concat length "The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet." source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Besides this query is misusing MySQL GROUP BY "feature" `SELECT p.ID, t.trid, ptrans.*, group_concat(pen.post_content SEPARATOR ', ') ... group by p.ID, t.trid` is non valid SQL.